# laravel ErrorException invoice system

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to get property 'invoice_prefix' of non-object

```
@if (!isset($invoice))
                        <div class="col-md-1"><b>OR</b></div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <a href="#" class="float-right1 select-existing-customer btn btn-warning btn-sm"> Select
                                Existing
                                Customer</a>
                        </div>
                        @endif
                        <div class="col-xs-2 float-right">
                            <div class="input-group ">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">#{{ $setting->invoice_prefix  }}</span>
                                <input type="hidden" name="invoice_id_test" value="{{  isset($invoice) ? $invoice->id  : '' }}"  id="">
                                <input type="text" name="invoice_id" readonly id="invoice_id" class="form-control required"
                                    placeholder="Invoice Number" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" value="{{  isset($invoice) ? $invoice->id  : $setting->invoice_initial_value }}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

im getting ErrorException

Comment: Provide the error which are you getting

Comment: Trying to get property 'invoice_prefix' of non-object

Comment: no problem, happy coding, don't forget to mark my answer as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking for the existence of `$invoice` variable but your `$setting` variable is probably empty, not existing, or not a type of object

Error is saying that invoice_prefix is not available inside $setting variable because is not a type of object. try to {{ dd($setting)  }} somewhere in your code to see what is inside that variable.

If $setting is an array for example you can get value like follows:

```
$setting['invoice_prefix']
```

If is null then problem is that you not assign any value to that variable therefore you are trying access property 'invoice_prefix' of non-object